# Не подключается к БД MySql через Java JDBC

Tags: java, mysql

Работаю в Netbeans.
Никак не могу подключить. Пароли и другие названия правильные, проверяла несколько раз.
Пробовала удалять "?serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow&useSSL=false". Не помогло.
Выдаёт вот такие ошибки:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'CustumersID ' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1167)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2851)
    at jvc1.JvC1.main(JvC1.java:21)
```

```
    package jvc1;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import static java.lang.System.*;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    public class JvC1 {

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYDB?serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow&useSSL=false";
            String user =  "root";
            String pwd = "QQ66QMAF";
            try{
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pwd);
                Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
                String query = "SELECT * FROM cust";
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()){
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt("CustumersID"+" "));
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("FirstName"+" "));
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("LastName"+" "));
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("Email"+" "));
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("phone"+" "));
                }
            }
                catch (SQLException se){se.printStackTrace();}

        }

    }
```

Comment: вам ошибку про неизвестный столбец говорит, значит все подклчилось и запрос пошел выполняться. вот только его нет.

Comment: `+ " "` за скобки уберите в `println`

Comment: @teran думаю стоит оформить как ответ

Comment: @Vartlok а как по мне - закрыть по опечатке